# What is 'Kill Ring' in XCode?

Tags: xcode

In XCode there's a really neat feature called "Kill Ring" which I get a hint what its about [here](http://www.rattlesnake.com/intro/Kill-Ring-Overview.html) but I don't know how to use it!!

How do you use the "Insert Kill Ring" feature in XCode?

Comment: What would really help is a reference to a __complete__ description of what all the xcode editor commands are..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.rattlesnake.com/intro/Yanking.html#Yanking

It's from Emacs.

Basically it's a list of copied entries which you can pop down through. If you've used later versions of Word or Excel, they have the same idea in their "paste lists" that show up when you copy things.

It allows you to copy two things in a row, then get back to the first thing.

Answer (score 1):

If the article [Customizing the Cocoa Text System](http://www.hcs.harvard.edu/~jrus/Site/cocoa-text.html) has anything to do with it, then it states:

> “kill ring” which large deleted blocks
>   of text get copied to

NSTextKillRingSize apparently sets the size of the kill ring.

Please read the above article, you'll probably understand it better than me.